# Having some problem in my calculation with javscript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, nsarray

I am trying to add a the values in an array untill the sum is 1000. I have been trying it using for loop with if condition. but it doesn't stop in according with sum value.
example array [110.110.225,130,150,100,240,170,100,110,...]
I want the loop to be stopped once the sum of values = 1000 or any other specific sum. 
Need help please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use a `break` statement in the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: Please also consider to update the title. It should contain _what_ the problem is, not _that_ you have a problem. Something like: **For-Loop doesn't stop when reaching breaking condition** helps that others having similar problems find your question and its answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function stopWhenSumEqualsN(n,A) {
  var n=n||500;
  var A=A||[110,110,225,130,150,100,240,170,100,110];
  let obj=A.reduce(function(a,v,i){
    if(a.sum<a.threshold) {
      a.sum+=Number(v);
      a.maxidx+=Number(1);
    }
    return a;
  },{sum:0,maxidx:0,threshold:n});
  let msg=Utilities.formatString('sum: %s maxidx: %s threshold: %s',obj.sum,obj.maxidx,obj.threshold);
  msg+='<br /><input type="text" id="nin" value="' + n + '" /> n<br />';
  msg+='<textarea id="Ain" rows="4" cols="60">' + A.join(",") +  '</textarea>A<br /><input type="button" value="Execute" onclick="runAgain();" />';
  msg+='<input type="button" value="Start Again From Scratch" onClick="google.script.run.stopWhenSumEqualsN();" />';
  msg+='<script>function runAgain(){let n=document.getElementById("nin").value;let A=document.getElementById("Ain").value.split(",");google.script.run.stopWhenSumEqualsN(n,A);}</script>'; 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg), "Results");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can we see an example of your code?

you can use a for loop to check for the sum and exist the loop using break if the sum reaches above your desired value.

this will notify about how many numbers were needed to reach 1000 and exist the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++) {

var sum = 0;
sum += numbers[i];

if (sum > 1000) {
  alert(i);
  break;
  }

}
```

Comment: this would also work with a while loop. Just use `break;` to exist the loop when you reach your desired value.

Comment: function tcharge(closer,currentmonth){
  var iniarr,charge,target,sum;
  charge = [];
  iniarr = mcharge(closer,currentmonth);
  
   for (var i=0; i < iniarr.length; i++){
     sum += iniarr[i][26];
     if (charged < 1000){
        charge.push(iniarr[i])
    }
}
return charge;
}

This is the code I want it to just show the arrays after the sum of iniarr[i][26] reaches 1000  for  specific person and specific month.